# java - Найти количество различных чисел в массиве

Tags: java

Дана последовательность целых чисел. Найти количество различных чисел в этой последовательности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int getUniqueNumbersQuantity(int[] array)
{
    Hashtable hash=new Hashtable();
    Integer iValue;
    for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        iValue=new Integer(array[i]);
        hash.put(iValue.toString(), iValue); //одинаковые значения "лягут" друг на друга
    }
    return hash.size();
}
```

Comment: вместо Hashtable надо бы Set<Integer> использовать

Answer (score 2):

1. перебираем числа в цикле
2. берем первый элемент последовательности, заносим его в переменную
3. сравниваем его с остальными и считаем количество совпавших
4. складываем результаты в какой нибудь хешмеп, где ключ - число, количество повторов - значение
5. берем второй и т.д.

Способов реализации много, можно посчитанные элементы хранить в отдельном массиве и новое число проверять его наличие в этом массиве, можно из основной последовательности их удалять, наверно можно придумать, что-то еще =)